# Change style of all elements with particular class apart from the first one?

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have the HTML

```
<div class="ms-rtelong"></div>
<input type="text" name="fname"></input>
<input type="text" name="lname"></input>
<div class="ms-rtelong"></div>
<div class="ms-rtelong"></div>
<div class="ms-rtelong"></div>
```

With

```
$('.ms-rtelong').css({'width':'650px', 'height':'300px'});
```

If I want to  change the size of all div's but want to leave the first one as it is, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [:gt()](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector should do it:

```
$('.ms-rtelong:gt(0)').css({'width':'650px', 'height':'300px'});
```